# get the full path (path + filename) of the currently editing file in to the OS clipboard

Tags: buffers, files

when editing a file (for example a .pl file)

Whats the quickest way to get the full path (path + filename) of the currently editing file in to the OS clipboard.

I'm on macOS, where `echo "hello" | pbcopy` works btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function I use, which you can bind to a keybinding. The link to the original author of the function is also provided.

```lisp
;; http://camdez.com/blog/2013/11/14/emacs-show-buffer-file-name/
(defun cpm/show-and-copy-buffer-filename ()
  "Show the full path to the current file in the minibuffer and copy to clipboard."
  (interactive)
  (let ((file-name (buffer-file-name)))
    (if file-name
        (progn
          (message file-name)
          (kill-new file-name))
      (error "Buffer not visiting a file"))))
```

Comment: great answer, only gripe is I feel this would put it in emacs clipboard, but not in OS clipboard.

Comment: ah - right. It puts it on to my mac clipboard, but that may be because I use `(setq select-enable-clipboard t)`

Comment: I meant to say "wouldn't" but I wrote "would"

Comment: With `(setq select-enable-clipboard t)` the function puts this both on osx clipboard and in the kill ring. I also set `(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)`, which means that it doesn't replace whatever is currently in the next kill ring slot. So I think, with those settings, the function should do everything you need. Or is the problem that you don't want to share the kill ring with the clipboard?